# How to block / delay execution of a mySQL query until the previous one has been completed in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql

I am trying to write a mySQL stored procedure that does the following:

```
1. insert a new row into table A;
2. read the new row from table A;
3. using information gleaned from step 2, insert a new row into table B
```

I need step 2 to wait until step 1 is finished, as table B uses one of the columns - to be more specific the autoincrement index - of table A as a foreign key. I cannot know what that value is until the new row has been inserted.

Usually, step 2 does take place after step 1 is finished, but I don't want any hiccups caused by a slow insertion or any other unforeseen factors.

On second thought, I probably also need mySQL to block any new insertions into table A until I have finished reading from it.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: Use a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html).

Comment: Could you show a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [transaction](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commit.html). This is exactly what they are for: avoiding inconsistent database states.

Also, for your step 2, you can use the [`LAST_INSERT_ID`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-routines-last-insert-id.html) function. Even if you do not use a transaction, this function will return the last ID inserted by the current connection; if other connections insert a row, it won't affect the result of `LAST_INSERT_ID()` in your connection.

So:

```
INSERT INTO people (name) VALUES ('John');
INSERT INTO addresses (person_id, address) VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'There');
```

is likely sufficient for what you need; if you have more complex logic, transactions will help:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- do anything
COMMIT;
```

A transaction is treated as a logical unit; other modifications to the database will either happen before or after the transaction, not during one.